# Is feature weighting is helpful for boosting Machine Learning model performance?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining, feature-engineering

I am a beginner in machine learning. I am looking to know, `is feature weighting is helpful for ML models & For which models performance improved and for which not.`

Comment: Hi @backlogGiash, welcome to the site. Is this homework or where does this quoted question come from?

Comment: @ncasas Thanks for your response. No, it is not homework. I am experimenting on a dataset. My code is very lage, so i am not sharing that. I just want to know theoratical background.